# Changing Lightswitch database connection at run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am looking to make it possible for my application to change it's connection string at runtime. I have a connection string in the Web.Config file, but when I update the config file and restart the application, the connection string does not update. Also, I do not seem to be able to use the configuration manager from within my application. Is changing the connection string in the Web.Config file the best way to go about making this a dynamic connection?

```
<add name="486f1ab5-d3c4-4fc5-805b-0afbcf0fa46b" connectionString="Data Source=.\MyServer;Initial Catalog=Mydatabase;Integrated Security=True" />
```

Comment: are you sure that you are even reading the correct key/value pair in your .config file can you show the snippet of the .config file along with the code of how you are reading from it using the ConfigurationManager..?

Comment: I inherited this so some of the details have become kind of lost. So I believe the connection object is managed by the the Lightswitch object in some way. I added the connect string to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a blog post that goes over what you need to do:

[LightSwitch Dynamic Connection Strings Now Supported](http://joshuabooker.com/Blog/Post/14/LightSwitch-Dynamic-Connection-Strings-Now-Supported)

Comment: I don't see it mentioned in the blog, but my project was created before this update. Will I need to recreate anything in the project?

Comment: Depending on what LightSwitch project version your project is, you will need to perform either an explicit or forced upgrade in order to upgrade the project to the latest LS project system (forced upgrade would be if it was v2 or v3, if you try to open it in VS 2013 it would "force" you to perform an upgrade, explicit would be if it is a v4 project, in this case you would need to right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose upgrade).  The project should still work after the upgrade, but I would definitely make a backup before performing the upgrade.

Comment: Ultimately you want this entry in your .lsxtproj file (also note that the extension of the LS "root" project file changes when you upgrade):

<LightSwitchProjectVersion>v4.5</LightSwitchProjectVersion>